# SQL Oracle - YY from date and add character

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am asking your help about a join I have to do.

I have a field **Date** as DD/MM/YYYY.
I have to join it on an other table with a field with data like **A14**, for year 2014 for example.

Do you know how can I get only the two last characters from field **Date**, add to it the character **A**, to to the join with my other table ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datefield is of date data-type, then

```
SELECT 'A' || TO_CHAR (DATEFIELD, 'YY') FROM MY_TABLE;
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT 'A' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YY') FROM MY_TABLE;
```

But I assume from your example, DATE is a string in format DD/MM/YYYY
You can probably try something like,

1. Convert the String to Date and get the year alone:

   `SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE 
   WHERE FIELD = (SELECT 'A' || TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(DATEFIELD,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YY') FROM MY_TABLE;`
2. Just use string - substring function as below:

   `SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE 
    WHERE FIELD = (SELECT 'A' || substr (DATEFIELD, -2) FROM MY_TABLE;`

For using join, You can do something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE, OTHER_TABLE
 WHERE OTHER_TABLE.FIELD = ('A' || SUBSTR(MY_TABLE.DATEFIELD, -2);
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE JOIN OTHER_TABLE
 ON OTHER_TABLE.FIELD = ('A' || SUBSTR(MY_TABLE.DATEFIELD, -2);
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to concatenation, and if your date field is actually a `DATE` not a string, you can include fixed values in a date format model if they're in double-quotes:

```
select to_char(sysdate, '"A"YY') from dual;

TO_
---
A14
```

So to join with that you could do:

```
select <columns>
from my_table
join other_table
on other_table.string_column = to_char(my_table.date_column, '"A"YY');
```

Answer (score 2):

just use concatenation and to_char with desired format for your date.

```
select 'A'|| to_char(<datefield>, 'YY')
```